# Thinkpad X201 battery sometimes shows 2% for a few hours

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, thinkpad

I am new here so thank you for the welcome! I am having a few issues with my Thinkpad X201 running Ubuntu 18.04 that I was hoping you could help me with.

Most of the time, everything is fine with a brand new battery off of ebay. Things work well.

Sometimes, completely randomly, the battery will jump from anywhere down to 5% then drain to 2% then stay at 2% for the next few hours (until it is fully drained I assume)

The laptop also sometimes randomly powers off completely, the logs show no errors or anything like that (as far as I can tell).

Please let me know if there is anything I can do or if you need more info. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to replace the battery. Because the battery itself is the source of the erroneous state of charge readings.